# Conversion from base 10 to another with ConTeXt

Tags: context

I took [this code](https://www.mathematex.fr/viewtopic.php?t=10501) to produce this `tex` file.

My question is : How to get the same result with ConTeXt?

My MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}



%----------------------------------------
%base 2
%----------------------------------------
    \def\makeatletter{\catcode`\@11\relax}
    \def\makeatother{\catcode`\@12\relax}
    \makeatletter

    \def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#1=12\relax}

    \def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
      \let\reserved@d=#1%
      \def\reserved@a{#2}\def\reserved@b{#3}%
      \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
    \def\@ifnch{%
      \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
        \let\reserved@c\@xifnch
      \else
        \ifx\@let@token\reserved@d
          \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
        \else
          \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
        \fi
      \fi
      \reserved@c}
    \begingroup
    \def\:{\global\let\@sptoken= } \:  % this makes \@sptoken a space token
    \def\:{\@xifnch} \expandafter\gdef\: {\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
    \endgroup


    \def\@ifstar#1{\@ifnextchar *{\@firstoftwo{#1}}}
    \long\def\@dblarg#1{\@ifnextchar[{#1}{\@xdblarg{#1}}}
    \long\def\@xdblarg#1#2{#1[{#2}]{#2}}

    \long\def \@gobble #1{}

    \long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}
    \long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
    \long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

    \let\@empty\empty

    \def\@carcube#1#2#3#4\@nil{#1#2#3}

    \def\@star@or@long#1{%
      \@ifstar
       {\let\l@ngrel@x\relax#1}%
       {\let\l@ngrel@x\long#1}}

    \let\l@ngrel@x\relax
    \def\newcommand{\@star@or@long\new@command}
    \def\new@command#1{%
      \@testopt{\@newcommand#1}0}
    \def\@newcommand#1[#2]{%
      \@ifnextchar [{\@xargdef#1[#2]}%
                    {\@argdef#1[#2]}}
    \long\def\@argdef#1[#2]#3{%
       \@ifdefinable #1{\@yargdef#1\@ne{#2}{#3}}}
    \long\def\@xargdef#1[#2][#3]#4{%
      \@ifdefinable#1{%
         \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{%
              \expandafter
              \@protected@testopt
              \expandafter
              #1%
              \csname\string#1\expandafter\endcsname
              {#3}}%
           \expandafter\@yargdef
              \csname\string#1\endcsname
               \tw@
               {#2}%
               {#4}}}
               
     \def\@testopt#1#2{%
      \@ifnextchar[{#1}{#1[#2]}}
    \def\@protected@testopt#1{%%
      \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
        \expandafter\@testopt
      \else
        \@x@protect#1%
      \fi}
     
    \long\def\@yargdef#1#2#3{%
      \@tempcnta#3\relax
      \advance \@tempcnta \@ne
      \let\@hash@\relax
      \edef\reserved@a{\ifx#2\tw@ [\@hash@1]\fi}%
      \@tempcntb #2%
      \@whilenum\@tempcntb <\@tempcnta
         \do{%
             \edef\reserved@a{\reserved@a\@hash@\the\@tempcntb}%
             \advance\@tempcntb \@ne}%
      \let\@hash@##%
      \l@ngrel@x\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\reserved@a}
    \long\def\@reargdef#1[#2]#3{%
      \@yargdef#1\@ne{#2}{#3}}
     
     \def\renewcommand{\@star@or@long\renew@command}
    \def\renew@command#1{%
      {\escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{{\string#1}}}%
      \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
         {\@latex@error{\string#1 undefined}\@ehc}%
         {}%
      \let\@ifdefinable\@rc@ifdefinable
      \new@command#1}
    \long\def\@ifdefinable #1#2{%
          \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string #1}%
         \@ifundefined\reserved@a
             {\edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\@carcube \reserved@a xxx\@nil}%
              \ifx \reserved@b\@qend \@notdefinable\else
                \ifx \reserved@a\@qrelax \@notdefinable\else
                  #2%
                \fi
              \fi}%
             \@notdefinable}
    \let\@@ifdefinable\@ifdefinable
    \long\def\@rc@ifdefinable#1#2{%
      \let\@ifdefinable\@@ifdefinable
      #2}

    \def\@ifundefined#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi}

    \newcount\@tempcnta
    \newcount\@tempcntb

    \long\def\@whilenum#1\do #2{\ifnum #1\relax #2\relax\@iwhilenum{#1\relax
         #2\relax}\fi}
    \long\def\@iwhilenum#1{\ifnum #1\expandafter\@iwhilenum
             \else\expandafter\@gobble\fi{#1}}
    \long\def\@whiledim#1\do #2{\ifdim #1\relax#2\@iwhiledim{#1\relax#2}\fi}
    \long\def\@iwhiledim#1{\ifdim #1\expandafter\@iwhiledim
            \else\expandafter\@gobble\fi{#1}}
    \long\def\@whilesw#1\fi#2{#1#2\@iwhilesw{#1#2}\fi\fi}
    \long\def\@iwhilesw#1\fi{#1\expandafter\@iwhilesw
             \else\@gobbletwo\fi{#1}\fi}
    \def\@nnil{\@nil}
    \def\@empty{}

    \ifx\@@input\@undefined
     \let\@@input\input
    \fi

    \def\input{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input}
    \def\@iinput#1{\@@input#1 }

    %\input{colordvi.tex}   

    \newbox\nb@box
    \newcount\nb@a
    \newcount\nb@b
    \newcount\iter@
    \newcommand\division[2][2]{%
       \def\dividende@{#2}\def\base@{#1}\iter@\@ne\division@{#2}{#1}}
    \newcommand\division@[2]{%
       \setbox\nb@box\hbox{\kern0.5em#1\kern0.5em}%
       \nb@a#1 \nb@b#1 \divide\nb@b#2
       \vtop{%
          \begingroup
             \multiply\nb@b#2 \advance\nb@a-\nb@b
             \hbox to\wd\nb@box{\hfil#1\hfil}%
             \vskip3pt\hrule height0pt width\wd\nb@box\vskip3.4pt
             \hbox to\wd\nb@box{\hfil\bf\color{red}{\number\nb@a}\kern0.5em}%
             \expandafter\xdef\csname reste@\number\iter@\endcsname{\number\nb@a}%
          \endgroup}%
       \setbox\nb@box\hbox{8}\vrule height\ht\nb@box depth3.5ex
       \setbox\nb@box\hbox{\kern0.5em\ifnum#2>\nb@b #2\else\number\nb@b\fi\kern0.5em}%
       \vtop{%
          \hbox to\wd\nb@box{\kern0.5em#2\hfil}%
          \vskip3pt\hrule height0.4pt width\wd\nb@box\vskip3pt
          \hbox{%
             \csname @\ifnum\nb@b>\z@ first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
             {\advance\iter@\@ne\gdef\maxiter{\number\iter@}%
              \expandafter\division@\expandafter{\number\nb@b}{#2}}%
             {\kern0.5em\number\nb@b\xdef\maxiter{\number\iter@}}}}}

    \newcommand\afficheresultat{$(\dividende@)_{10}=(\afficheresultat@\maxiter)_{\base@}$}
    \newcommand\afficheresultat@[1]{%
       \csname reste@#1\endcsname
       \ifnum#1>\@ne
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\afficheresultat@
       \else
          \expandafter\@gobble
       \fi{\number\numexpr#1-1}}
    \makeatother
    
    
    
    \begin{document}
        
  \division{21}     
    
    \afficheresultat    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Does it matter if that's done from the MetaPost end of ConTeXt?

Comment: Btw the easy part is the conversion (either in Lua or MetaPost via a recursive algorithm). The hard part is the arrangement.

Comment: Why not if we get the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've said, the difficult part is the arrangement. Lua is an overkill, so MetaPost should suffice.

**Edit:** Using Metafun's `passvariable` and `\MPrunvar`, explained in [Metafun's manual, section 15.8](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf), our generated string is visible to TeX and we can directly typeset it after our division. As a friendly recommendation, to exploit ConTeXt capabilities, you must learn some basics of MetaPost and Lua. I'm pretty sure you'll do it eventually, right?

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
%n and base are arguments to our graphic
\startuseMPgraphic{tobase}{n,base}
vardef tobase(expr n, Base) =
    save N, c, u, p, q, s;  N := n; c := 0; u := 2.4EmWidth;
    pair p; p := right+down; pair q[];
    string s; s := "";
    image(
    forever:
        %Nodes
        q[1] := c*p;
        q[2] := q[1]+(1,0);
        q[3] := q[1]+(0,-1);
        %Lines
        q[4] := q[1]+(1/2,1/2);
        q[5] := q[1]+(1/2,-3/2);
        q[6] := 1/2[q[4],q[5]];
        q[7] := q[2]+(1/2,-1/2);
        %Text
        draw thetextext("\strut " & decimal N, u*q[1]);
        draw thetextext("\strut " & decimal Base, u*q[2]);
        draw thetextext("\bf\strut " & decimal (N mod Base), u*q[3]) withcolor red;
        draw (u*q[4]) -- (u*q[5]);
        draw (u*q[6]) -- (u*q[7]);
        %Dirty trick to support bases greater than 10
        %Don't use it for bases greater than 36
        s := 
        if (N mod Base > 9):
            char(55 + (N mod Base))
        else:
            decimal (N mod Base) 
        fi
        & s;
        N := floor(N/Base); c := c + 1;
        exitif N = 0;
    endfor;
    %We're actually able to pass content to TeX, yay!
    passvariable("converted", s);
    draw thetextext(0, u*c*p);
    )
enddef;
draw tobase(\MPvar{n},\MPvar{base});
\stopuseMPgraphic
\def\tobase#1#2%
    {\useMPgraphic{tobase}{n=#2,base=#1}%
    $(#2)_{(10)}=(\mathrm{\MPrunvar{converted}})_{(#1)}$}
\def\division#1{\tobase{2}{#1}}
\starttext
\division{21}
\blank
\tobase{7}{243}
\blank
\tobase{16}{511}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! That's what I want.

Comment: @Aviroum Notice the MetaPost function graphs a conversion for bases other than 2. Since you only asked for base 2, my macro definitions only accept one argument. However, it ain't difficult to pass the base as an additional argument.

Comment: How to pass  additional argument ? I am not MetaPost user :(

Comment: @Aviroum See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you ! Perfect! One word.I will do my best for learning MetaPost. Any suggestion for starting ? Easy 

Comment: @Aviroum Since it seems you speak French because of the spaces after punctuation signs, https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/metapost/f-mpman-2.pdf and https://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html are good starting points. Also, the manual I linked in the answer is a good reference to Metafun, the MetaPost dialect used with ConTeXt.

Comment: I am also a French speaker, and used also this document as a starter (couldn't open Jairo's second link, so might repeat it) http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/metapost/base/mpintro.pdf